# Report with BIRT and Embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, birt

the question in very simple... 
I'm currently developing an app in java with reports, for that, i used birt, but, i don't want install tomcat, because i will not can in production
I searched on google, and the result is very poor.
can somebody help with this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a BIRT engine with in your applications war. Just include content of birt.war in your application's war and define servlets for birt.
[See here for details](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2879835/Using-the-BIRT-Report-ViewerAJAX-based-J2EE-application)